# Callback before destroy and before associated records destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observers

I have the following model:

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :personal_phone_numbers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :people, :through => :personal_phone_numbers
end
```

I want to set up an observer to run an action in a delayed_job queue, which works for the most part, but with one exception.  I want the before_destroy watcher to grab the people associated with the phone number, before it is destroyed, and it is on those people that the delayed job actually works.

The problem is, when a phone number is destroyed, it destroys the `:personal_phone_numbers` record first, and *then* triggers the observer when it attempts to destroy the phone number.  At that point, it's too late.

Is there any way to observe the destroy action *before* dependent records are deleted?

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't ideal, you could remove the `:dependent => :destroy` from the `personal_phone_numbers` relationship, and delete them manually in the observer after operating on them.

However, I think that this issue might be showing you a code smell. Why are you operating on people in an observer on phone number. It sounds like that logic is better handled in the join model.

Comment: My work around was to observe the join model.  The high level logic is about looking for duplicate accounts, and watching all forms of contact info is part of that process.  It's not a code smell so much as a "real world tries to trash the database" smell.

Answer (score 0):

Use alias_method to intercept the destroy call?

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :personal_phone_numbers, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :people, :through => :personal_phone_numbers

  alias_method :old_destroy, :destroy

  def destroy(*args)
    *do your stuff here*
    old_destroy(*args)
  end
end
```

Comment: My main problem with that is that I want this in an observer because it doesn't directly pertain to phone numbers, and having this code in the model would be more of a code smell that @cjhveal mentions...  (plus the observer watches a number of models)

Comment: I agree with @DGM but as an aside can destroy call super() rather than alias_method approach?

Comment: @TJChambers the joys of discovering answers from years ago! :) Yeah, I think super would certainly be the better approach. I'm not a big fan of the observer technique with regards to stuff like this; I'd now prefer to have a single defined place (class method?) to handle cleaning up, rather than relying on automatic catches.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem in a nutshell is that you want to gather and act on a collection of `Person` when a `PersonalPhoneNumber` is destroyed. This approach may fit the bill!

Here is an example of a custom callback to collect `Person` models. Here it's an instance method so we don't have to instantiate a `PersonalPhoneNumberCallbacks` object in the ActiveRecord model.

```
class PersonalPhoneNumberCallbacks
  def self.after_destroy(personal_phone_number)
    # Something like people = Person.find_by_personal_phone_number(personal_phone_number)
    # Delayed Job Stuff on people
  end
end
```

Next, add the callback do your ActiveRecord model:

```
class PersonalPhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy PictureFileCallbacks
end
```

Your `after_destroy` callback will have the model passed down and you can act on its data. After the callback chain is complete, it will be destroyed.

**References**

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#relational-callbacks
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a before_destroy callback in the model, then grab the data and do whatever operation you need to before destroy the parent. Something like this example should be what you are looking for:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
before_destroy :execute_random_method


private

def execute_random_method
  ...
end
handle_asynchronously :execute_random_method
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit old but thought I'd share that rails now has the nice ['prepend'](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object) option for the before_destroy callback now. This goes follows the same line of thought with [tomciopp had](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11855348/4848156) but allows you to define the before_destroy whereever in the class.

```
before_destroy :find_associated_people, prepend: true

def find_associated_people
  # using phone number, find people
end
```