# Rails belongs_to associations and destroy callbacks not seeing original record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following 3 models:

```
class ExitSurveyResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey_response, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :attendance
end

class SurveyResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :question_responses, class_name: 'SurveyQuestionResponse', dependent: :destroy
  has_one :exit_survey_response, dependent: :destroy
end

class SurveyQuestionResponse < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :response
  validates :response, length: { maximum: 255 }
  belongs_to :survey_question
  belongs_to :survey_response

  before_destroy :destroy_attendance_cache

  private
  def destroy_attendance_cache
    logger.debug('The following is nil because it was already deleted')
    logger.debug("exit_survey_response: #{survey_response.exit_survey_response}")
  end
end
```

The problem is, when I delete an `ExitSurveyResponse`, I need to modify the `attendance` record associated with it. But I need to do so in the `SurveyQuestionResponse` object when it is deleted. Problem is, if I do that, the `ExitSurveyResponse` is already deleted. Is there a way to delay the deleting of `ExitSurveyResponse`s until after the dependents are destroyed?

To be clear, I always need to update the `attendance` when a `SurveyQuestionResponse` is destroyed. But a `SurveyQuestionResponse` can be destroyed either directly (easy to handle), when a `SurveyResponse` is destroyed or when an `ExitSurveyResponse` is destroyed.

Comment: Would a `before_destroy` hook in `ExitSurveyResponse` work for you?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan - that's a great idea. I don't like that I'd be calling 2 destroy callbacks (I still need the `SurveyQuestionResponse` destroy callback in case that or the `SurveyResponse` object is deleted), but I think this would solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm - I am imagining that you would need to update the `attendance` in all cases of `ExitSurveyResponse` destroy, irrespective of whether it is due to destroy of `SurveyResponse`, yeah? In which case you may end up having to handle it..

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan - it's really about the `SurveyQuestionResponse` objects. When it's destroyed, the associated `attendance` needs updating. It just happens that destroying an `ExitSurveyResponse` also destroys its `SurveyQuestionResponse`.

Comment: Would `handle_asynchronously :execute_random_method` be of any help here? I can't find any documentation on it, but it's suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654014/callback-before-destroy-and-before-associated-records-destroyed

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan - I've been playing with `before_destroy` in `ExitSurveyResponse`, but it's a lot trickier than it seems. If I do that and update the `attendance` what actually happens is the `attendance` is updated twice! Because just by accessing the `attendance` makes deleting the `SurveyQuestionResponse` now see the original `ExitSurveyResponse`!! And that's a problem...

Comment: @RichPeck - `handle_asynchronously` doesn't seem to be what I want. If a call is delayed I won't have the objects I need to update `attendance`.